# get rid of previous commits, moving origin/head origin/master

Tags: git, github

I somehow got my local repos (c9.io and my web server) out of sync and it's a huge mess.  I tried to git pull, and then push changes and each time it screws up the other location.

What I'd like to do is get rid of all commits after e39a8ac, so I stop getting the behind 10 commits message.  I tried doing a git rebase and revert and reset, but I don't know how to fix it.

PLEASE HELP.  Git is good sometimes, but otherwise I feel lost.

[image: Photo of my sourcetree]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can try using force-push: `git push -f origin master`.  That may suffice.  It may not.  It may do *too much*.  Be very careful with this.

It's often better, instead, to add *new* commits that undo the things you don't want done, and leave the previous commits in there, and then just push the new state.  Git is great about adding *new* commits, and there's no danger like there is with force-push.

#### Description

Remember that when using Git, you have *your* repository, and everyone else (such as `c9.io` for one, and your web server for another perhaps) has *their* repository.  You can do whatever you want to *your* repository.  Getting *them* to do what *you* want to *their* repository is harder.

Your image shows that your `master` is pointing to `e39a8ac`, which is what you say you want.  So *your* repository is OK now.  Note that we refer to this as "`master` points to `e39a8ac`".

You have, in your repository, a short name `origin` that abbreviates a URL.  At that URL, there is another Git with another repository.  You can run `git fetch origin` to have your Git connect to their Git and obtain new-to-you commits from them.  If and when you do this, your Git will record, in your repository, *their* `master` as your `origin/master`.  This is how your Git remembers for you what it last saw over there.  It looks like you did that, or something equivalent to that, at some point.

(So far this is all just setting things up so that you can see what I'm talking about below.)

You can also run `git push origin <hash-or-branch-name>:<their-branch>` to have your Git connect to their Git send them any new-to-them commits.  (Any commits they already have, you don't have to send.)  Your Git then asks their Git, politely, if it would mind please setting its branch name to the commit-hash you have your Git suggest to them.  They can refuse for any reason, but if they're cooperating with you, they are likely to refuse only for one reason: that your request would cause them to *lose* some commit(s).

Hence, you can run:

```
git push origin master:master
```

(which you can abbreviate as just `git push origin master`<sup>1</sup>) to *ask* them to please set *their* `master` to `e39a8ac`.  The problem is that they will notice that this would lose *at least* five commits—the five we can see in your image—and almost certainly another 5 (your own Git says that you are "ten behind" them, based on your Git's memory of their Git's `master`).

Git is very, *very* much oriented to this concept of "adding new commits".  [It's always happy to assimilate new distinctive technology into its Borg Collective.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek))  But it tends to balk at the idea of taking stuff *away*.

Still, you can try using a "force push":

```
git push --force origin master:master
```

This changes your Git's polite request, *please update your `master` to `e39a8ac`*, into a command: *Update your `master` to `e39a8ac`!*  Whether they will obey is another question entirely; it's up to them and their Git and their settings.  If they do obey, that will erase some commits from their repository.  That might be just what you want, and if it is, you *may* be done here.

But remember, there may be *many* repositories.  Suppose they take your command, and now your Git has your master pointing to `e39a8ac` and their Git has their `master` pointing to `e39a8ac` (so that your `origin/master` also points to `e39a8ac`).  But then a third Git comes along and says to them: *Hey, I have `4a3c63d` and nine more commits you could add to your `master`, would you like them?*  Git being so Borg-like, their Git may immediately snarf them up and put them back into *their* repository ... and now if you connect your Git to their Git, you'll get those same commits back.

For the force-push to "take", you must convince *every* Git user that has a copy of the repository to set *their* `master` back, so that they *all* throw out the ten commits you will be throwing out.  If there are just the two repositories, you're good.  If there's a third one but you convince them to do this too, you're good.  Otherwise, consider an alternative: instead of trying to *remove* commits you don't like, just add yet another new commit that sets things back the way you *do* like them:

```
* 4a3c63d (origin/master) Merge ...
|\
| * dcca8ec  made ONE CHANGE to console log
* | aa6b21e  changed console log
* | ...
```

Suppose you added one new commit, let's just call it `nnnnnnn`,<sup>2</sup> that puts every file back the way you want it:

```
* nnnnnnn (master) Put everything back the right way
* 4a3c63d (origin/master) Merge ...
|\
| * dcca8ec  made ONE CHANGE to console log
* | aa6b21e  changed console log
* | ...
```

If you now run `git push origin master`, your Git will offer their Git this new commit.  They will greedily gobble it up and add it to their collective, and set their `master` to `nnnnnnn` too.  And now you and they will match up, and any third Git that connects to them will pick up `nnnnnnn`, and so on.

The drawback is that this leaves some useless commits behind, with their versions of all those files.  But generally that's not terribly harmful (unless those files have secret passwords in them, or are multi-gigabyte movie or DVD images, or whatever).

---

<sup>1</sup>If you leave out the `:master`, the default is that your Git asks them to set the same name you give: `git push origin master` => `git push origin master:master`; `git push origin xyz` => `git push origin xyz:xyz`; and so on.  You can even specify more than one thing at a time: `git push origin master xyz:hello` means `git push origin master:master xyz:hello`.

<sup>2</sup>It's too hard to predict the next commit's hash ID.  Even Git doesn't know yet, because one of the inputs Git uses to make it is the exact time at which you make it.  Every second sooner or later changes the ID completely, even if everything else about the commit is exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you!  git push -f origin master updated the remote to match what I wanted to keep, and now all my branches are up to date at the same place.  I appreciate that!